# How can I split wordlist from a file

Tags: python

Hello guys I want to split words from a selected file but It returns ['0']

in my text file I have email:password like this email@gmail.com:password

I want to split them into a list

emails = ['email@gmail.com']
passwords = ['password]

```
path = easygui.fileopenbox()

print(path)
username = []
passwords = []

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    lineCount = len(f.readlines())
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in str(lineCount):
        username = re.split(':',line)
        password = re.split(':',line)
```

Comment: It's possible for both passwords and email addresses to contain a `:`, so this split is only reliable if you control the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
import re
usernames = []
passwords = []

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       line = line.strip()
       match = re.match(r'^.*?@\w+?\.\w+?:', line)
       if match:
           username = line[:match.end() - 1]
           password = line[match.end():]
           usernames.append(username)
           passwords.append(password)
```

Comment: It say ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: That means there is either an email address or a password that has the `':'` character in it and is causing the split statement to make more than two splits.

Comment: @dracoludiodraco  Try my updated answer.

Comment: @dracoludiodraco  With this solution it wouldn't skip lines with multiple `':'` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file and read one line at a time. Split the line on colon which should give two tokens (assuming the file format is as stated in the question). Append each token to the appropriate list.

```
usernames = []
passwords = []

with open(path) as data:
    for line in map(str.strip, data):
        try:
            pos = line.index(':')
            usernames.append(line[:pos])
            passwords.append(line[pos+1:])
        except ValueError:
            pass # ignore this line as no colon found
```

Comment: It say ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @dracoludiodraco Did you notice in my answer where I said "assuming the file format is as stated in the question"? Clearly there are lines in the file that contain more than one colon. Maybe you should edit the question to show what the file really looks like. In the meantime I've edited my answer to operate slightly differently which may solve your problem

Comment: @dracoludiodraco That doesn't fix the problem... all it does is skip lines that have multiple `':'` characters.

Comment: It's okay to skip lines for me anyways

Comment: @Alexander Wrong. It skips lines that have **no** colons

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("test") as file:
    content=file.read()
    email,password=content.split(":")
print(email,"=======",password)
```

[image: code]